# subgroup generated by 2 and 7

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the group $(\mathbb Z, +)$ the subgroup generated by $2$ and $7$ is

1. $\mathbb Z$
2. $5\mathbb Z$
3. $9\mathbb Z$
4. $14\mathbb Z$

I am confused between option 1 and 4. Please Help me.

Q2.Find the smallest subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ containig $8$ and $13$

1. 8$\mathbb Z$

2.$\mathbb Z$

3. 13$\mathbb Z$

4.104$\mathbb Z$

Is its answer 104$\mathbb Z$ because if group contain 8 and 13 then it must contain their l.c.m. Am i right?

Comment: Question 1 and question 2 are the same, just with different numbers. It is true that the smallest subgroup et cetera must contain the l.c.m. of the generators. However, it contains much more than that. For instance, it makes sense for the smallest subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ containing $8$ and $13$ to contain $13$.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 Take into account that

$$(-3)\cdot2+1\cdot 7=1$$

Q2 Observe that $\;lcm(8,13)=104\;$ .

For both questions above, in particular the second one, you could try to do some examples and then have an educated guess.